# Chat flag button has wrong hover text

Tags: bug, flags, chat, design, moderator-tools

The flag hover text on the chat is wrong. It says

> Moderator flags are seen only by the site-moderators, and should be used to indicate serious issues with a message, and other administrative issues.

but in reality every mod gets the notification (according to mods). It should say that WHO flags the post is seen by only site moderators (as PPCG moderator Dennis said [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39663718#39663718)).

[image]
[image]

Comment: <pedant> When you're on https://chat.stackexchange.com, "site-moderators" means people with moderator powers in that chat domain, so it's actually correct. </pedant>

Comment: @Randal'Thor well a clarification would be better because all mods have it

Comment: Yes, exactly, and all mods have moderator powers on https://chat.stackexchange.com/ :-)